# Failure notification with multiple profiles

Tags: sql-server

In my SQL Server Agent having several jobs which are running with different Proxies... and in Database mail having more than one profile [each profile having individual accounts]... now my question is , how can I send a mail using a specific profile from Database mail for failure notification...

Thanks 
Kiran Kumar

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will use the default mail profile on alerts. On the otherside if you need to specify a special mailaccount or some other error handling, just create a step in your job which will be executed in the case of an error which uses sp_sendDbMail to send the alert.

If you just want to change the alert sender for ALL of your jobs, you can change it by right clicking your sql server agent, select properties, alert system and there you go. See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177408(v=sql.105).aspx).